# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, deep-learning, lstm, sklearn-pandas

Here is my code..

```
    import imp
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
    from sklearn import metrics
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

    for title, metric in metrics.items():
        print(title, metric(labels_categorical_dev.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1)))
    print(classification_report(labels_categorical_dev.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1)))
    y_pred = model.predict([message_first_message_test, message_second_message_test, message_third_message_test])
```

Iam getting below error..

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "getopt.py", line 6, in

```
for title, metric in metrics.items():
```

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'items'

I have tried with versions from scikit-learn=0.20.0 to scikit-learn=0.24.2

But still getting this error. Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: As is written, metrics has no attribute items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share more details about what is the purpose of your code? As you can see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics), there isn't any attribute of `sklearn.metrics` named `items()`.

`.items()` is used for dictionaries in order to get the values pertaining to different keys in that dictionary.

Also, you have defined `y_pred` after it has been referenced, so that will cause an error as well.

Comment: Yes. I have solved it by removing.. from sklearn import metrics    AND      
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score     . Thank you for your time.